# Splitting an object into multiple object and pushing them in an array in javascript(Possibly using underscore/lodash)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I want to split an object in an array based on a criteria.
If i get json response like this :-

```
var obj = { dataSo : [{ key1 : "value1", key2 : "value.1.2", key3 : ["value1.3.1","value.1.3.2"]},
            { key1 : "value1", key2 : "value.2.2", key3 : ["value2.3.1","value2.3.2","value.2.3.3"]},
            { key1 : "value1", key2 : "value.3.2", key3 : ["value.3.3.1"]},
            { key1 : "value1", key2 : "value.4.2", key3 : []}]}
```

Then i have to check whether key3 has got more than one value.If it does contain more than one value then i should copy that whole object while keeping the key3 value different and make copies of it and pushed it into array as new object.

For e.g from previous data i should make something like this :-

```
{ dataSo : [{ key1 : "value.1.1", key2 : "value.1.2", key3 : "value.1.3.1"},
            { key1 : "value.1.1", key2 : "value.1.2", key3 : "value.1.3.2"},
            { key1 : "value.2.1", key2 : "value.2.2", key3 : "value.2.3.1"},
            { key1 : "value.2.1", key2 : "value.2.2", key3 : "value.2.3.2"},
            { key1 : "value.2.1", key2 : "value.2.2", key3 : "value.2.3.3"},
            { key1 : "value.3.1", key2 : "value.3.2", key3 : "value.3.3.1"},
            { key1 : "value.4.1", key2 : "value.4.2", key3 : "" }]}
```

How can I achieve this effectively?

Comment: What do you mean by "effectively"? Best performance, and if so in terms of memory or time? Shortest code?

Comment: In terms of Time, less code, avoiding to many loops .

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`, explode each element into an array of subelements, one for each value of `key3`. Then paste them back together with `concat`:

```
obj.dataSo = [].concat(...obj.dataSo.map(({key1, key2, key3}) =>
  key3.map(key3 => ({key1, key2, key3}))
);
```

Note that this solution does not handle values for `key3` which are not arrays, and if `key3` is empty, it will omit the corresponding element. To fix this, preprocess `key3`:

```
obj.dataSo = [].concat(...obj.dataSo.map(({key1, key2, key3}) =>
  (!Array.isArray(key3) ? [key3] : key3.length ? key3 : [""]) .
    map(key3 => ({key1, key2, key3}))
});
```

This solution uses ES6 features such as the spread operator, destructuring, and object literal shorthand.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer . It's a very great solution.I want to know though what is {key1, key2, key3} , to me it seems like an object. But since it does not have key value pair .I am not sure what it is as i m not much acquainted with ES6. Actually i have like 12 keys in my object but since this was example i key it to only 3 keys. So i want to make it bit dynamic i.e why i want to change this {key1,key2,key3} ,so it can take varying keys.Thanks!